# What is wrong with my .htaccess file with 301 redirect giving 500 internal server error uploaded via Filezilla?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, filezilla, godaddy-api

One of our businesses shutdown and we want to redirect the pages from that old website to our new one, based on relevant content for SEO.

Our site is hosted using Wordpress Managed Hosting on GoDaddy. GoDaddy told me that they don't let anyone edit Managed Wordpress htaccess files, but instead, I should use Filezilla.

I was able to access my .htaccess file for our old site and create 301 redirects for it. I made a backup of the original and left it on the server and uploaded the new .htaccess but then I get a 500 internal server error when I upload the new file. Anyone notice anything wrong with my process or the code?

I have used a 301 code calculator to make sure my code was correct
I made sure the filetype was correct (created in notepad, saved as All Files - UTF-8)
I cannot access cpanel on GoDaddy - I must use external server access for this as they do not support Managed Wordpress Hosting edits.
I made sure the file was called .htaccess
I have made sure to rename my backup so it doesn't interfere.
I added https:// to my URL instead of http:// since I was told that might affect the issue.
I have tried putting the whole URL for the old site in the code, instead of just the appendage (i.e. https://theglenwoodvenue.com/celebrations/ instead of /celebrations).

```
# BEGIN GD-SSL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.+)$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^theglenwoodvenue\.com$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=300"
</IfModule>
# END GD-SSL


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Redirect 301 /celebrations/ https://irregardlesscatering.com/glenwood- 
closing-message-homepage/
```

the page should redirect to a new domain (from https://theglenwoodvenue.com/celebrations/ to http://irregardlesscatering.com/glenwood-closing-message-homepage/)  -- this 301 redirect is just one I am testing, there will be plenty more but I couldn't even get this one to work.

Comment: Remove "/"  after celebrations and try again.

Comment: Try Redirect 302 /celebrations/  https://irregardlesscatering.com/glenwood- 
closing-message-homepage

Answer (score 0):

if you are not aware with the htaccess 301 redirection then you can use  simple this plugin in wordpress it's easy to use 
also you can install directly this plugin from your wordpress plugin add new plugin option and plugin name is  **Redirection**

https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/